# Como alinhar dinamicamente a margem de uma label via código windowns form?

Tags: c#

Tenho a `lblStatus` que serve para atribuí 4 valores diferentes de acordo com a consulta e cada valor tem um tamanho diferente, assim não tem como eu formartar direto pela propriedade a posição. Então gostaria de setar a posição direto pelo código para cada Status.

Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
if (string.Compare(objPed.PedStatus, "L") == 0)
                {
                    objPed.ConsultarNFPedido();
                    lblStatus.Text = " LIBERADO " + objPed.PedDtLib + " NOTA FISCAL: " + objPed.pedNFNumero + " SÉRIE: " + objPed.pedNFSerie + " ST: " + objPed.pedNFStatus;
                    lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                }
                else if (string.Compare(objPed.PedStatus, "A") == 0)
                {
                    lblStatus.Text = "PENDÊNCIA DE FATURAMENTO";
                    lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
                }
                else if (string.Compare(objPed.PedStatus, "E") == 0)
                {
                    lblStatus.Text = "PEDIDO EXCLUÍDO EM " + objPed.PedDtAlt + " POR " + objPed.PedIdAlt;
                    lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.DarkRed;
                }
                else if (string.Compare(objPed.PedStatus, "P") == 0)
                {
                    lblStatus.Text = "AGUARDANDO PAGAMENTO";
                    lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.Blue;

                }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coloque as seguintes propriedades no Label:

```
//Auto size off, o tamanho da label, não vai seguir o tamanho do texto
label1.AutoSize = false;

//Dock = o tamanho da label, vai ficar ancorado no controle pai
label1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; //ou DockStyle.Top; 

//Vai alinhar o texto sempre no meio
label1.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
```

E então é só colocar a label onde você quer q ela fique.